# Regular expression in bash to match multiple conditions

Tags: bash, grep

I would like to implement a regular expression in bash that allows me to verify a series of characteristics on a dataset.
A sample is attached below:

```
id, date of birth, grade, explusion, serious misdemeanor
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1
582,1999-05-12,8.51,0,1
9274,2001-25-12,9.65,0,0
21,2006-14-05,0.53,4,1
```

id is required to have only 3 digits, date of birth less than 2000, minimum grade point average is 5.60 with the second decimal place being other than 0, and at least one expulsion or serious misconduct.

The result of executing the regular expression should be:

```
582, 1999-05-12, 8.51, 0, 1
```

I have tried to implement the following regular expression and it does not give me any result.

```
grep -E "^\d{0,3},[0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9].*,[1-5].[0-5][1-9],[1-9],[1-9]$"
```

Any idea?

Comment: When you get into "date of birth less than 2000" and "minimum grade point average is 5.60", you are leaving the realm of regexes. You may be able to come up with some shenanigans to make it "work", but it will be like driving nails with a screwdriver.

Comment: It would be "in bash" if you were using `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]`. This isn't a bash-specific question in any meaningful way -- `grep` is provided by your OS vendor, not by the shell, and would behave the same way if you started it from Python or Java on a system that didn't have bash installed at all.

Comment: BTW, `\d` is PCRE syntax. **Some** versions of `grep` support it as an extension, but the POSIX standard doesn't require them to; the standard alternative is `[[:digit:]]`.

Comment: ...and really, this is a job for awk, not grep.

Comment: These requirements are ridiculously specific. Is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

If it is mandatory to use `grep`, would you please try:

```
grep -E '^[0-9]{1,3},1[0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{2}){2},(5\.[6-9][1-9]|[6-9]\.[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]+\.[0-9][1-9]),([1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]+|[0-9]+,[1-9][0-9]*)[[:space:]]?$' input_file
```

Result:

```
582,1999-05-12,8.51,0,1
```

- `[0-9]{1,3}` matches if `id` has 1-3 digits. (I have interpreted `only 3 digits` like that. If it means differently, tweak the regex accordingly.)
- `1[0-9]{3}(-[0-9]{2}){2}` matches if the `birth year` is before 200 *exclusive*.
- `(5\.[6-9][1-9]|[6-9]\.[0-9][1-9]|[1-9][0-9]+\.[0-9][1-9])` matches if `grade` is greater than 5.60 with the second decimal place being other than 0.
- `([1-9][0-9]*,[0-9]+|[0-9]+,[1-9][0-9]*)` matches if either or both of `explusion` and `serious misdemeanor` have non-zero value.

Comment: Hi! @tshiono I've tried yout code and everything works exept the regular expression for matching if either or both of explusion and serious misdemeanor have a non-zero value. ..

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Would you please elaborate about the case the last regex does not work well? My understanding of the requirement is it matches if at least one of `explusion` or `explusion` have a positive number. It that correct?

Comment: Thanks to you for your help. Yes! Your interpretation's correct, at least one must be positive, but when I try the code I get no result. I've tried to modify it but I get nothing ...

Comment: I imagine your file has DOS line endings. I have modified my regex to match it. How about now?

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions do not understand numeric values, and they certainly do not understand boolean logic. All it knows is text. You'll need to use an actual programming language like Awk or Perl to do this.

Here's an example:

```
$ perl -l -a -F, -E'say if length($F[0])>3 || $F[2] < 5.60' foo.txt
123,2005-01-01,5.36,1,1
9274,2001-25-12,9.65,0,0
21,2006-14-05,0.53,4,1
```

This call to `perl` splits apart the fields on commas, and then prints the line if the length of the first column is over 3, or the value of the third column is less than 5.60.

This is just a starting point, but this is the direction to go.

Comment: your code looks good but I have the condition to use grep....Do you have any idea?